# PonyORM (Python) "Value was updated outside of current transaction" but it wasn't

Tags: python, sql, orm, transactions, ponyorm

I'm using Pony ORM version 0.7 with a Sqlite3 database on disk, and running into this issue:  I am performing a select, then an update, then a select, then another update, and getting an error message of

```
pony.orm.core.UnrepeatableReadError: Value of Task.order_id for
   Task[23654] was updated outside of current transaction (was: 1, now: 2)
```

I've reduced the problem to the minimum set of commands that causes the problem (i.e. removing anything causes the problem not to occur):

```
@db_session
def test_method():
    tasks = list(map(Task.to_dict, Task.select()))
    db.execute("UPDATE Task SET order_id=order_id*2")
    task_to_move = select(task for task in Task if task.order_id == 2).first()
    task_to_move.order_id = 1

test_method()
```

For completeness's sake, here is the definition of `Task`:

```
class Task(db.Entity):
    text = Required(unicode)
    heading = Required(int)
    create_timestamp = Required(datetime)
    done_timestamp = Optional(datetime)
    order_id = Required(int)
```

Also, if I remove the constraint that `task.order_id == 2` from my select, the problem no longer occurs, so I assume the problem has something to do with querying based on a field that has been changed since the transaction has started, but I don't know why the error message is telling me that it was changed by a different transaction (unless maybe `db.execute` is executing in a separate transaction because it is raw SQL?)

I've already looked at this similar question, but the problem was different ([Pony ORM reports record "was updated outside of current transaction" while there is not other transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995555/pony-orm-reports-record-was-updated-outside-of-current-transaction-while-there)) and at this documentation (https://docs.ponyorm.com/transactions.html) but neither solved my problem.

Any ideas what might be going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pony uses optimistic concurrency control by default. For each attribute Pony remembers its current value (potentially modified by application code) as well as original value which was read from the database. During UPDATE Pony checks that the value of column in the database is still the same. If the value is changed, Pony assumes that some concurrent transaction did it, and throw exception in order to avoid the "lost update" situation.

If you execute some raw SQL query, Pony does not know what exactly was modified in the database. So when Pony encounters that the counter value was changed, it mistakenly thinks that the value was changed by another transaction.

In order to avoid the problem you can mark `order_id` attribute as `volatile`. Then Pony will assume, that the value of attribute can change at any time (by trigger or raw SQL update), and will exclude that attribute from optimistic checks:

```py
class Task(db.Entity):
    text = Required(unicode)
    heading = Required(int)
    create_timestamp = Required(datetime)
    done_timestamp = Optional(datetime)
    order_id = Required(int, volatile=True)
```

Note that Pony will cache the value of `volatile` attribute and will not re-read the value from the database until the object was saved, so in some situation you can get obsolete value in Python.

**Update:**

Starting from release 0.7.4 you can also specify `optimistic=False` option to `db_session` to turn off optimistic checks for specific transaction that uses raw SQL queries:

```
with db_session(optimistic=False):
    ...
```

or

```
@db_session(optimistic=False)
def some_function():
    ...
```

Also it is possible now to specify `optimistic=False` option for attribute instead of specifying `volatile=True`. Then Pony will not make optimistic checks for that attribute, but will still consider treat it as non-volatile

Comment: is there any other solution apart from using volatile?

Comment: Yes, now it is possible to specify `optimistic=False` option for db_session. I've updated the answer